# Не могу выйти из GIT в терминале Mac (➜ ~ git:(main) ✗)

Tags: git, консоль, mac

После установки Git на MAC не могу выйти из него в терминале. Не могу открывать другие программы в терминале макбука (Jupyter notebook и другие программы) так как нахожусь в директории Git ((➜  ~ git:(main) ✗)). Как выйти из него в обычную консоль терминала.

Comment: `Ctrl-D` не помогает?

Comment: Ctrl-D не помогает ,появляется надпись Saving session...completed.

[Процесс завершен], меня просто выкидывает из терминала, захожу обратно и опять весит надпись ➜  ~ git:(main) ✗

Comment: *"Не могу открывать другие программы"* - ¿а что при этом происходит? Нахождение в директории с git-репозиторием не должно как-то припятствовать их исполнению.

Comment: Ну смотрите, хочу зайти в jupyter notebook выдает это:  ➜  ~ git:(main) ✗ jupyter notebook
zsh: command not found: jupyter
➜  ~ git:(main) ✗

Comment: Это обычная консоль. У вас висит декоратор, который печатает статус гита перед каждым вводом. Его можно убрать. Проверьте переменные среды `PROMPT_COMMAND`, `PS1`, `PS2`.

Comment: Ну так вы вроде как по-прежнему находитесь в той же консоли. `command not found: jupyter` говорит о том, что что-то сломалось в PATH или консольных алиасах. ¿Откуда раньше бралась эта команда?

Comment: (Проверьте переменные среды PROMPT_COMMAND, PS1, PS2). А какая команда нужна для того, чтобы их проверить. Я недавно начал с терминалом разбираться, поэтому туплю)

Comment: Вызвал PROMPT_COMMAND, PS1, PS2 : echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
echo $PS1
echo $PS2
выдало %(?:%{%}%1{➜%} :%{%}%1{➜%} ) %{%}%c%{%} $(git_prompt_info)
%_>

Comment: `git_prompt_info` украшает приглашение командной строки. Но он ничему не мешает. Если вас он беспокоит, отредактируте `~/.bashrc`. Только сохраните копию до того как начнёте. К отсутствию `jupyter` это не имеет никакого отношения.